# VS2015 Apache cordova not running

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual studio 2015 and I installed apache cordova on it, but when I am trying to run the app on emulator or device it gives me blue bar with 'Build started...' than 'Ready' but nothing happen.
what can i do ?!

Comment: Could you please try clear the cordova cache? You can find it under `Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Cordova Tools->Clear Cordova Cache`.

Comment: May I know that you are getting any message in the **output** tab?

Comment: now it works ... thank you :)